# SQL Server - remove string of characters from within longer string where value to be removed is in different places from record-to-record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2016.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID  Categories
1   XMDO1, EFA02, EFA04, EMDO1, XMDO2
2   EFR02, LFA02, UFA04, RMED1, XMDO1, XMDO2
3   ELR02, GFF02, XFA04, VMED1, XMDO1
```

...along with 2,000 similar records, where any code can appear in any order in the string.

How would I construct a query to delete XMDO1 from all of the above records, such that the resulting table looks like this?

```
ID  Categories
1   EFA02, EFA04, EMDO1, XMDO2
2   EFR02, LFA02, UFA04, RMED1, XMDO2
3   ELR02, GFF02, XFA04, VMED1
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why isn't `Categories` normalized into its own foreign relation?

Comment: @Dai, I inherited this mess and I have the same question.  I will be changing it as soon as I can!

Comment: @Dai - there's no time like the present! Good luck with this.

Comment: Lucky your codes can't overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing:

```
-- First pass (cases where XMD01 is not the first item):

UPDATE
    tableName
SET
    Categories = REPLACE( Categories, ', XMD01', '' )

-- Second pass (cases where XMD01 is the first or only item):

UPDATE
    tableName
SET
    Categories = REPLACE( Categories, 'XMD01', '' )
```

These can be combined:

```
UPDATE
    tableName
SET
    Categories =
        REPLACE( REPLACE( Categories, ', XMD01', '' ), 'XMD01', '' )
```

If you want an accurate rowcount and maybe slightly faster performance then add a `WHERE` clause like this (and reformatted for readability):

```
UPDATE
    tableName
SET
    Categories =
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                Categories,
                ', XMD01', -- Cases where XMD01 is not the first item.
                ''
            ),
            'XMD01', -- Cases where XMD01 is the first or only item.
            ''
        )
WHERE
    CHARINDEX( 'XMD01', Categories ) > 0
```

Comment: is it normal with this kind of REPLACE query that the result said that ALL records of the table were affected, even though not all records contain XMDO1?

Comment: @Stpete111 Query does not know the replace was the same value

Comment: @Stpete111 Yes, but don't worry. That's normal.

Comment: @Stpete111 I've amended my answer with a single-statement version that also adds a `WHERE` clause for an accurate rowcount (but it will behave identically to my first answer).